# Have a custom text list in Excel with datavalidation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a custom dropdown (not the kind of dropdown from Developer mode) where I join three strings together, but can figure it out.

Date I want a dropdown list from:
[image]

Basically the list needs to have the following items:

- Dranken/Boissons/Drinks
- Frisdranken
- Bieren
- Sterke dranken
- Eten/Manger/Food

[image]

I know I can make the list with Data Validation and use  `=OFFSET($A3;0;0;COUNTA($A3:$A50))` and I know I can format my strings with `=TEXTJOIN("/";TRUE;$A3:$C3)`, but I can't seem to combine them. I get that it doesn't make sense to add a TEXTJOIN as a reference in OFFSET, but what could be used instead?

Comment: How about adding a new column with `textjoin` formula and setting list source at that column

Comment: That's a rly great idea. I wanna see if anything else comes up where I can have it in 1 go, else this will probably be the way to go